# can't enter text into element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

why i'm getting "InvalidArgumentException" when trying to enter text into angular input element.
NOTE: i'm getting xpath from csv file

```
class TimeSheet:

    def __init__(self):
        c_options = Options()
        self.__driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=c_options)
        self.__action = None

    def enter_text_into_element(self):
        text = self.__action['enter_text']
        element = self.__driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.__action['xpath'])
        element.clear()
        print('text cleared')
        element.send_keys(text)

   def click_function(self):
        click_status = False
        element_clicked = self.__driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.__action['xpath'])
        try:
            element_clicked.click()
            click_status = True
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
        return click_status

ts = TimeSheet()

for index, task in enumerate(tasks):
    ts.set_action(task)
    print(ts.get_step(), end=": ")
    print(ts.get_action())
    
    if ts.get_action() == 'click':
        ts.click_function()
    elif ts.get_action() == 'text':
        ts.enter_text_into_element()
```

#Error Traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\PycharmProjects\testSelenium\timesheet_automation.py", line 116,
> in 
> ts.enter_text_into_element()   File "C:\PycharmProjects\testSelenium\timesheet_automation.py", line 82, in
> enter_text_into_element
> element = self.__driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.__action['xpath'])   File
> "C:\PycharmProjects\testSelenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
> return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "C:\PycharmProjects\testSelenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 976, in find_element
> return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {   File "C:\PycharmProjects\testSelenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 321, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\PycharmProjects\testSelenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid
> argument: missing command parameters

Comment: Please include the full traceback

Comment: you can check traceback now

Comment: Looks like your xpath is invalid. Print the xpath just before using it to search.

Comment: What is your browser/driver version? Are they in sync?

Comment: i'm using chrome browser and chrome driver version 86.0.4240.22

Comment: ok problem solved when i click on element , element xpath is changed so now it's working